# Is there a click bubbling in Swing components?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

In my Java Swing project, I want to listen to the same click on `JPanel` and on `JButton` at the same time. But it seems that when I click the button it fires `actionPerformed` only on this button.

Comment: You need to add a MouseListener instead. Override mouseClicked or mouseRelased methods.

Comment: *"same click on JPanel and on JButton"* Explain to me how this works for the user. As a (hypothetical) user of this software, I'd be confused that clicking a button ***and*** a panel does the same thing or achieves the same result. BTW: *What* is being done on click?

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer I'm not confident that would work for what the OP *seems* to want to do. Even with a mouse listener attached to the panel, it won't fire when the user clicks the button, as the `ActionEvent` will take priority over the `MouseEvent` (the panel does not have input focus).

I chose 'not confident' and 'seems' carefully, as I'm really not sure what the OP wants to do or what this is supposed to achieve. I suspect it's an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). OP should clarify a variety of things for the best answers.